# CakePhp 2.0 Prefix Routing

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have uncommented the line

```
 Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

but when i bake it, i do not get admin_index views or functions in controller... the routes.php file is also unchanged...

Comment: Did you "assign your admin prefix to the scaffolding variable: `public $scaffold = 'admin';`" ?

Comment: The interactive bake process should ask you at some point whether you want to build CRUD stuff for admin routes as well. So just use `cake bake` and use the interactive menu's, rather than immediately using `cake bake controller foo`.

Comment: found what was the issue... when baking needed to add --admin in the end... now works fine... thanks anyway...